# Redis vs dynamoDb geolocation tracking

Tags: websocket, redis, geolocation, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently a bit confused into which database to use for geolocation Tracking. What I want to do is update the location of a group of people every 30 secs. The data is sent to the server using web-sockets. Each user has an Id in the database and I would like to update the location of that user every 30 second. After doing so, I would like to query these locations and show it in real time to another group of users. My question is what is the advantage and the disadvantages of DynamoDb and Redis. Which one is faster and can scale easier. I am expecting almost 2 million QPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both can scale fairly well, but this depends heavily on your use case and architecture.

DynamoDB is a cloud based NoSQL storage system, and Redis is an in memory data structure store. This means that queries to DynamoDB would involve making a roundtrip to Amazon's servers, while queries to Redis would be over RAM (so, much, much lower latency).

As a consequence of the above, the amount of data you can store in Redis would be limited by the RAM available on your hardware. That said, in the event of Redis or your hardware crashing for some reason, you would have to be content with some level of data loss. You can mitigate this somewhat by configuring Redis persistence so that Redis writes to disk regularly (either every N seconds or by manually triggering a write in your code) and mitigate further by then copying those writes to S3 or elsewhere. This trades performance (depending on your scale) for data safety somewhat due to I/O latency. See [the documentation for Redis persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) and [this blog post](https://githubengineering.com/moving-persistent-data-out-of-redis/) by the GitHub engineering team mentioning their decision to remove Redis persistence for performance reasons.

Meanwhile all of the issues above are abstracted away for you by DynamoDB since [AWS handles availability](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-internet-scale-data-storage-the-nosql-way/) for you behind the scenes. You are really only limited by [how much you can afford](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) and usage (read/write per second) [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html).

DynamoDB does not have native support for querying and inserting geospatial data (although [there is a library for it](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo), but it seems to be unmaintained), [Redis does](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd). You could write your own code for this.

[DynamoDB does not have support for namespacing](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85964), or rather, DynamoDB is namespaced by your AWS account meaning you would not be able to maintain a separate DynamoDB instance with the same table names (say for production vs dev data) on the same AWS account. Redis doesn't either, but you can trivially spin up a separate Redis instance for this.

See also [Redis MEMORY USAGE command](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage) and [Redis memory optimization](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) docs.